# Delete auto Increment node from firebase android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Want to delete this auto increment.
How to get this key and how to delete it, can someone please tell.

I am Getting id below Chats i.e. - DhbjEJRmYAZhBMEDZn8szjprd4F2YTSLXgg2qfMMVygXzVdehosJx3a2 and so on according to the position by :-
DatabaseReference mChatReference = **mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("chats").child(chatId);**

I have tried like
**DatabaseReference mChatReference mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("chats").child(chatId).push();**

but i am getting wrong node(Key).

how to get inside node key .
Pls help.. any helpwould be appreciate.

Comment: When you are calling `push()` you are always generating a **new** key. Have you tried to store the pushed key in the object once you add it to the database, so it can be used later?

Comment: NO i havent , i just wanted to know how to get the autoincrement node.

Comment: Saving it once you generate it, and use it whenever needed.